# json not displayed properly --

Tags: html, json

I am trying to do my json assignment on creating 4 card profiles - each with a picture and background profile.

I seem to manage to create the 4 picture properly but not the background profile. I only managed to displayed the 1st background profile initially using absolute and relative positioning, so I changed to float and managed to display all 4 background profiles but at the bottom, instead of the right side of each picture profile.

I did the exact same thing on both picture and background profile but not sure why only the picture works. Would appreciate and thanks in advance for your help and inputs.

```
        let pictureHTML = data.map(function(data) {
            return data = `
            <div class="name-title-bottom>">
                <img class="profile-img" ${data.picture}>
                <li class="data-name">${data.name}</li>
                <li class="data-jobTitle">${data.jobTitle}</li>
            </div>
            `
        });    


        let dataHTML = data.map(function(data) {
         return data =`
            <div class="right-side">
                <ul>
                <li class="data-jobTitle">Company: ${data.Company}</li>
                <li class="data-name">School: ${data.School}</li>
                <li class="data-name">Experience: ${data.Experience}</li>
                <li class="data-jobTitle">School: ${data.School}</li>
                <li class="data-name">Major: ${data.Major}</li>
                <li class="data-jobTitle">Email: ${data.Email}</li>
                <li class="data-email">${data.LinkedInUrl}</li></ul><br></div>
            `
        });


        $(".hook").append(pictureHTML);
        $(".hook2").append(dataHTML);

        });

.main{
// position: relative;
padding: 80px 80px 130px 10px;
display: inline-block;

.right-side{
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    // position: absolute;
    // top: 180px;
    // right: 0px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.name-title-bottom{
    // position: absolute;
    // bottom: 0;
    // left: 200px;
    float: left;
    padding: 30px 30px 30px 40px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

Comment: First of all, why `return data = \`<div`? You probably want just `return \`<div`.

Comment: Corrected. Thanks for the input. What puzzled me is that the picture profile (left section) seems working fine but the background profile (right section) does not.. not sure if I could do a screenshot to illustrate this..

Comment: It's working because the result of `data = 'some string'` is equals to `some string`.

Comment: `<img class="profile-img" ${data.picture}>` need to be `<img class="profile-img" src="${data.picture}" />`

Comment: Can you give an example of how `data` is looking?

Comment: Mosh, many thanks for the correction. The card should look like a staff pass (picture and name on left; and employee profile ie company name, school graduate from, major, emai addressl and linkedin on the right side. Thanks in advance for looking into this!

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {

            var data = [ 
                {
                "picture": "src=img/unsplash-headshot.jpg",
                "name": "Steve Smith",
                "jobTitle": "Project Manage",
                "Company": "Front End Dev Co",
                "Experience": "3 years",
                "School": "UW",
                "Major": "Marketing",
                "Email": "steve@fedc.com",
                "LinkedInUrl": "steve.linkedinprofile.com"
                }
                ];